# Signature of method with 'new Class()' as parameter

Tags: java, methods, parameters, signature

I saw a line of code where I don't know what the signature of that method looks like. I've searched online for some examples and an explanation, but didn't find one.

The line of code:

```
Circle sum = Circle.add(new Circle(), new Circle());
```

I was wondering how the signature of the add method would look like with the 'new Circle()' as parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without knowing this API, you can use the following hints:

- This method receives two parameters (or more...) of types `Circle` and returns an object of type `Circle`.
- The method is accessed through the `Circle.add(...)`, so it must be a `static` method

So the signature for this method will look something like:

```
public static Circle add(Circle c1, Circle c2);
```

or

```
public static Circle add(Circle... circles);
```

(the access modifier of the method can be other than `public`)

Comment: I'm guessing it's static, but otherwise this. Some explanation of why would be nice though.

Comment: @user2478398 thanks, you are right, I've missed the way this method is accessed. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I've also update it to include @YCF_L use of varargs, in case more than two `Circles` are allowed

Comment: Technically, the parameters could be some supertype of `Circle` and the return value could be some subtype of `Circle`, though I'd consider it very unlikely in this case.

Comment: Personally I think the varargs are unnecessarily complicated. Technically it could be one mandatory, then varargs, or two mandatory and then a varargs parameter of any other type. But there's no reason to believe it is from the context.

Comment: @ShmulikKlein Thanks you for the information! I knew it was a static method, but I've never seen a method using parameters in this way! Your answer is helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Signature is possibly:

```
add(Circle, Circle)
```

`new Circle()` is no-params constructor call.

Answer (score 1):

Because it take same Object `Circle` Object, i also suggest it can take an `array` of `Circle` and return a `Circle` Object in the end like this :

```
public class Circle{

    public Circle() {
    }

    public static Circle add(Circle...circles){
        Circle c = ...;
        //do soemthing
        return c;
    }
}
```

Or simply your class conscructor can take two `Circle` like this :

```
public class Circle{

    public static Circle add(Circle c1, Circle c2){
        Circle c = ...;
        //do soemthing
        return c;
    }
}
```